# Use different structure for grails unit tests

Tags: testing, grails, location

I have a very simple package structure, only one level deep for all my grails artifacts- the name of the application "estra"- because the grails application structure is already providing the separation folders. But when writing unit-tests all the classes are inside the same estra.* package and I want to keep them separated like this estra.domain, estra.controllers, etc.

Right now everything works fine, but the tests are pretty simple. Will I face any problem in the future with dependency injection or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the package name don't influence in your test since in your test class you "say" which class is tested, using the `@TestFor` annotation. But remember that in unit tests you need to manually set your dependencies.

```
class ServiceOne {
  def serviceTwo  
}

@TestFor(ServiceOne)
class ServiceOneTests {
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    service.serviceTwo = new ServiceTwo() //or mocked instance...
  }
}
```